# How to convert an array into array on objects mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'd like to convert an array into an array of objects objects for every document in an a collection

`ids: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`

to

`data: [ {id: 1, ..}, {id: 2, ..}, { id: 3, ..}]`

Comment: Can you provide a sample document before and after?

Comment: like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/aMM3JQUop8Z)?

Comment: @cmgchess yes that's correct, if I wanted to add more keys in the object, should I do it in the script now or add them in later? Lets say I have another field, channels.one and I want to move that so it's {id: 1, channel: channel.one }

Comment: In map you can create multiple fields

Comment: For some reason in the playground it works, but when I run it on my test database, it keeps setting data as null in every document. Maybe I need to use updateMany?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following code

```
[
  {
    $addFields:
      /**
       * newField: The new field name.
       * expression: The new field expression.
       */
      {
        newIds: {
          $map: {
            input: "$ids",
            as: "this",
            in: {
              id: "$$this",
            },
          },
        },
      },
  },
]
```